# Grails returning one element from each object

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to just return a single string from each object.

Given the following:

```
 class Book {
String title
Date releaseDate
String author
Boolean paperback
}
```

for every instance of Book I want to get an array of authors then make them unique.
I thought you could do something like:

```
def authors =  Book.findAllByAuthor()
```

This just gives me an array off book objects.
I know i can do a

```
a =[]
authors.each{a.add(it.author)}
a.unique()
```

I am almost certain there is a way just to grab all authors in one line.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you distinct authors of any book:

```
  Book.executeQuery("select distinct author from Book")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use projections to get a distinct list of authors across all books. Take a look at the [createCriteria documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) for more examples.

```
def c = Book.createCriteria()
def authors = c.list() {
  projections {
    distinct('author')
  }
}
```